Generate points that follow a given distribution
Given the probability density function and the cumulative distribution function calculated in the following way, I would like to generate M pseudo-random numbers that follow the distribution. To do this in one dimension, I used the inversion method, but now I'm having trouble applying it in two dimensions. Does anyone know how to do it? Or is there an alternative method to achieve the same goal?
a = 4; % Limiti per x e y
N = 50; % Numero di valori equidistanti
M = 100000; % Numero di punti da generare
nBin = 30; % Numero di bin per l'istogramma

% Generazione dei punti e calcolo dell'errore
x = linspace(-a, a, N);
y = linspace(-a, a, N);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
% Costruzione del campo di errore 
sigma = 1; 
mu1 = [-a/2, -a/2]; 
mu2 = [a/2, a/2]; 
err1 = exp(-((X - mu1(1)).^2 + (Y - mu1(2)).^2) / (2*sigma^2));
err2 = exp(-((X - mu2(1)).^2 + (Y - mu2(2)).^2) / (2*sigma^2));
err = 14 * err1 + 7 * err2;

% Normalizzazione per ottenere una densità di probabilità
densita_di_prob = err / sum(err(:));

% Calcolo della funzione cumulativa congiunta
funzione_cumulata = cumsum(cumsum(densita_di_prob, 1), 2);
funzione_cumulata = funzione_cumulata / funzione_cumulata(end);


You will need to adapt the inversion sampling technique to two dimensions.
Generally, you will have to compute the cumulative distribution function (which you have already done via funzione_cumulata) by taking their sum of both dimensions. Proceeding that, you will need to generate two independent sets of uniform random numbers for the x and y dimensions, which will be mapped into the CDF.
What I tried for the matlab script is:
% Step 1: Generate uniform random numbers for sampling
u1 = rand(1, M); % M random samples for the x-dimension
u2 = rand(1, M); % M random samples for the y-dimension

% Step 2: Find corresponding x, y points using inverse transform sampling
x_generated = zeros(1, M);
y_generated = zeros(1, M);

for i = 1:M
    % Find the x, y indices in the CDF that correspond to u1(i) and u2(i)
    [~, x_idx] = min(abs(funzione_cumulata(:, end) - u1(i))); % Find x index
    [~, y_idx] = min(abs(funzione_cumulata(x_idx, :) - u2(i))); % Find y index

    % Convert indices to x, y coordinates
    x_generated(i) = x(x_idx);
    y_generated(i) = y(y_idx);
end

% Plot the generated points
scatter(x_generated, y_generated, '.')
title('Generated Points Following the Desired Distribution')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')

For the URN u1 and u2 are uniform random numbers in [0, 1] which correspond to the random variables to be mapped using CDF. For each generated URN, you will need to find the corresponding indices in the funzione_cumulata. I did it via min(abs(...)) approach to find the closest CDF value to the random uniform number.
You could alternatively try rejection sampling but I'm not too familiar with how to do that. I believe this Stack post will assist with that...
Sampling using rejection method

I just used google translate for your comments.
